# Pandas, how to create multiple sheet?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'd like to make several sheets with pandas.

This is my test code

```
import pandas as pd

number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
name = ['john', 'james', 'ken', 'jiny']
df = pd.DataFrame(number, columns=['number'])
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test1_sheet')
writer.save()
```

output

[image]

I currently has created with a single test sheet name ("test1_sheet"). Additionally, I would like to add "test2_sheet" with "name" data list to the same Excel file (test.xlsx). For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(name, columns=['name'])
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test2_sheet')
```

I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Make 2 data frames; save them with the same writer with different sheet names. What's wrong with your approach?

Comment: The [Pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) provide quite detailed instructions on how to do that, note the `with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:` part in particular.

Comment: Don't declare  the Writer 2nd time. One time is enough otherwise it will not work as you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your data, it would look like this.

```
import pandas as pd

number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
name = ['john', 'james', 'ken', 'jiny']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(number, columns=['number'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(name, columns=['name'])

# now write to excel
with pd.ExcelWriter('text.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test1_sheet')
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test2_sheet')
```